# Dynamic values passing to sparkSQL

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Basically I am passing the dynamic values in pyspark SQL. My code is detailed below:

```
set_sql = "".join(["set app_list_0 = 'app_3'"])

    sqlContext.sql(set_sql)

    click_app_join_sql = sqlContext.sql("select click_id, (case when app_new in ${app_list_0} then 1 else 0 END) as  ${app_list_0}, device, os, channel from clickDF ")

    click_app = sqlContext.sql(click_app_join_sql)

    click_app.show(3)
```

When I ran my code, I end up with the following error. Can you please advise me what went wrong in the above code.

```
File "/home/saureddi/spark/data_process/hive_data_process.py", line 103, in <module>
    click_app_join_sql = sqlContext.sql("select click_id, (case when app_new in ${app_list_0} then 1 else 0 END) as  ${app_list_0}, device, os, channel from clickDF ")
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 384, in sql
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 603, in sql
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/spark2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 73, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nno viable alternative at input '(case when app_new in 'app_3''(line 1, pos 39)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect click_id, (case when app_new in 'app_3' then 1 else 0 END) as  'app_3', device, os, channel from clickDF \n---------------------------------------^^^\n"
```

Code:

```
app_sql = "".join(["select a.app, CONCAT('app', '_',a.app) as new_app, a.app_count from(select app, count(app) as app_count from dblclk_text.click_data group by app )a order by a.app_count desc limit 5"])
df1 = hiveContext.sql(app_sql)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('app')
df1_new_app = sqlContext.sql("select new_app from app ")
df1_new_app.printSchema()

app_list = []
app_result = df1_new_app.collect()

print(type(app_result))

for app in app_result:
    app_list.append(app)

click_sql = "select click_id,CONCAT ('app', '_', app) as app_new, device, os, channel from dblclk_text.click_pank_data"
clickDF = hiveContext.sql(click_sql)

clickDF.createOrReplaceTempView('clickDF')

app_list_0 = str(app_list[0])
#app_list_0 = 'app_3'

print (app_list_0)

sample_sql = '''select click_id, (case when app_new in {0} then 1 else 0 END) as  {0}, device, os, channel from clickDF '''.format(app_list_0)
click_app_join_sql = sqlContext.sql(sample_sql)
click_app = sqlContext.sql(click_app_join_sql)
click_app.show(3)
```

Comment: The way you are assigning dynamic variables is wrong I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_sql = '''
select tenant, user_id, event_type,bounce_class from {0}
where {1} and  {2} and  {3} and  {4}
and (event_type in ('list_unsubscribe', 'link_unsubscribe', 'spam_complaint') or bounce_class in ('10','30','90'))
and tenant is not null
and tenant != '' 
'''.format(table_name, dateid_start, dateid_end,event_timestamp_start,event_timestamp_end)

HiveContext.sql(sample_sql)
```

table_name, dateid_start, dateid_end,event_timestamp_start,event_timestamp_end are python values.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have made changes as suggested. I could see the values are populated but end the up with "no viable alternative at input". error details below:  pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nno viable alternative at input '(case when app_new in app_3'(line 1, pos 39)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect click_id, (case when app_new in app_3 then 1 else 0 END) as  app_3, device, os, channel from clickDF \n---------------------------------------^^^\n". Please advise me.

Comment: Hi Vijay, I have added the complete code in the  question with sub heading. Please check and help me out

Comment: Hi Vijay, I am able to pass the values dynamically but the query is throwing an error as detailed belew: pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nno viable alternative at input '(case when app_new in 'app_3''(line 1, pos 39)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect click_id, (case when app_new in 'app_3' then 1 else 0 END) as  app_3, device, os, channel from clickDF \n---------------------------------------^^^\n". do you know what could be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: the error was because of parenthesis () missed. its sorted out now.